# Display Table Records from AS400 to Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, record, ibm-midrange, display

I'm trying to display the records from PYLEAVE table, but when I use this code, it shows error SQL0204, can someone help me?

```
Call takeconnectionas400()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Open()
    adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from PRIMA.PYLEAVE", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    adapter.Fill(ds, "PRIMA.PYLEAVE")
    DGVAS400.DataSource = ds.Tables("PRIMA.PYLEAVE")
    DGVAS400.ReadOnly = True
```

Comment: Was there more to the error message than that? Searching suggests that the table name is wrong in the query. (It might also be that you are connecting to the wrong database, so it wouldn't find the table there.) And the code seems to be missing a line to Dispose of the connection.

Comment: SQL0204: PYLEAVE in PRIMA type *FILE not found.

Comment: This is the new code, DB name is PRIMA, table name is PYLEAVE

Comment: Check your connection string.  Make sure you're connecting to the correct server.  Also check the user id you're using.  Though you would normally get a proper security error if you aren't authorized, I've sometimes seen the 0204 error when the file's there but you aren't allowed to see it.

Comment: try your query on strsql on your iseries and say me if query work

Comment: The comment from Esperento57 is an excellent first step. Copy/paste your SELECT statement into either STRSQL or iNavigator's 'Run SQL scripts'. Verify for us that the SELECT runs by itself first. (In STRSQL, you might need to specify "PRIMA/PYLEAVE" instead of `PRIMA.PYLEAVE`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 for IBM i, the syntax for the table is not `DBNAME.TABLENAME` it is `SCHEMA.TABLENAME`  In old AS/400 terminology, that is `LIBRARY.FILE`  Have your IBM i administrator tell you what schema (library) the table is in and change your SELECT statement appropriately.

I don't know VB, but in JDBC you specify the database name in the connection string, not the SELECT statement.

Comment: I'm new to i Series, but must specify the schema (library) in queries with either System i Navigator or from within VB. Though there may be a connection string parameter or something like MySQL's `USE` command I don't know about.